# Magento ::: auto display products from child categories on top (parent) category without 'is anchor'

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

All my products are assigned to sub categories - I want All products to also display on the parent categories without explicitly assigning them.

`is anchor` is not good for me, because it does not use the seo-friendly urls for the sub categories, and this is an important requirement for me.

Is there another way I can achieve this, even with an extension?

Comment: Look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272736/magento-display-products-from-childcategories-if-parent-category-is-empty/8760866#8760866

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"is anchor" is fine as long as you have the canonical urls set correctly.
We use Mageworx SEO Suite to control this and it works well